# Openvpn client routing not always working

Tags: networking, ubuntu, routing, openvpn

I use a server with openvpn and pptp daemons.

In iptables I have rules to give some pptp clients permission to have contact with other clients through pptp or openvpn tunnels, available on the server.

```
Elevated pptp client --> pptp server forward to --> pptp client
Elevated pptp client --> pptp server forward to --> openvpn client
```

This works quite well, but:

Every once in a while I can't contact an openvpn client. When I ping the ip of the openvpn client I get a time-out, while I can ping that ip directly from the server!

```
server --> openvpn client == 64 bytes from *** time *ms
Elevated pptp client --> server == 64 bytes from *** time *ms
Elevated pptp client --> pptp server forward to --> openvpn client == time-out
```

The server is an ubuntu 14.04 server, but in my last server running ubuntu 10.10 I had the same issue.

I think the problem is as follows: ping message goes like this:

```
elevated client --> server routing --> openvpn daemon routing --> client
                                       openvpn daemon routing <-- client
```

The openvpn daemon cant find the ip to answer to in his own pool, and drops the message.

Is there any way to confirm this and if it is the problem: why does I only happend to some clients and how will I find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to this.

I push routes to the client. The client is sometimes earlier with performing the route add than the TAP/TUN interface is up. the route is ignored.

No I added to the clients a secondairy script to run when the interface is up where I can put my routes.

Now lets hope we never have to change them, because we would need to edit every client....